# Apache remove 'www' not working

Tags: apache, web, url-rewriting, subdomain

I've been trying all the suggestions on here to remove 'www' from my sub-domain, but nothing seems to work.

To cut a long story short (or at least shorter), we've recently launched a site womeninleadership.managers.org.uk, however an error was made in some printed material and the URL www.womeninleadership.managers.org.uk has been sent out in some material.

I've been trying to use the following RewriteRules to fix this, but have had no success at all:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]



  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The site is Codeigniter based which is why I also have the second rule.

Hoping someone here can point out where I'm obviously going wrong because this is really doing my nut in lol

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always used something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I've already tried a setup like that without any luck. There must be something else I'm doing wrong as the Rewrite Rules appear to be correct. Thanks again anyway.

Comment: Well, are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled on your server?

Comment: Yes, I have a few sites all running on the same server (using vhosts) and mod_rewrite is enabled as some require it. It's just the 'www' rule that isn't working. The second rule (in the same .htaccess file) works without issue, however the first rule doesn't.

Comment: Well, the stuff in my answer is straight from my server, so I'm sure it works.